# Can we define biological age?

Tags: senescence, telomere

How can we define ageing from a biological standpoint without making an appeal to chronological age?

Related, but less important, are there any metrics we can use to determine someone's biological age other than their chronological age?
Telomere length is an obvious candidate, but [it is imperfect](http://biomedgerontology.oxfordjournals.org/content/66A/2/202.full).

Comment: Basically, you're looking for some indices allowing to estimate the age of an organism, is it correct? If you meant estimating the "real biological age" rather than the "chronological age" then, the problem of finding indices is just the same as defining biological age. And just like any words, you can define them the way you want if you're the first to use them. Are you only interested in humans or can we talk about stuff like [dendrochronology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrochronology)?

Comment: I guess what I had in mind was about humans. If something is correlated with chronological age, its not necessarily a part of ageing. What definitions of ageing are there to clarify when something is part of ageing and when something is just correlated but not causally related?